# Convert from IList<T> to non-generic IList

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, c#-2.0

I am implementing `IListSource` that requires a method `GetList()` with the following signature:

```
IList GetList()
```

I am using .NET framework 2 and I'm wanting to return an object that implements IList as follows:

```
public System.Collections.IList GetList()
{
    return this._mydata; // Implements IList<MyDataRow>            
}
```

But I get a compile error saying: `Cannot implicitly convert type MyData to System.Collections.IList`.

If I create a **new** list of type `List<MyDataRow>`, populate it and return this list object, then it works. So in other words, this works:

```
public System.Collections.IList GetList()
{
   List<MyDataRow> list = new List<MyDataRow>();
   foreach (MyDataRow row in this._mydata)
   {
       list.Add(row);
   }
   return list;
}
```

But it seems very inefficient to have to recreate the list just to get it from type `IList<T>` to `IList`. Why is it that I can return a `List<MyDataRow>' from 'GetList()`, but not an `IList<MyDataRow>`? Does anyone know of a way for me to return the `IList<MyDataRow>` without repopulating a new list?

UPDATE:

The `_mydata` member variable is declared:

```
private MyData _mydata;
```

And `MyData` is declared:

```
public class MyData : IList<MyDataRow>
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: What is the declared type of the `_mydata` field?

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu: According to the error message he gets, it's `MyData`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why is it that I can return a `List<MyDataRow>` from `GetList()`, but not an `IList<MyDataRow>`

This is because `List<T>` implements `IList`, `IList<T>` cannot be cast to `IList` they are 2 separate interfaces. So to answer your question:

> Does anyone know of a way for me to return the `IList<MyDataRow>` without repopulating a new list?

If the concrete type implements `IList` (which `List<T>` does) then you can explicitly cast it e.g.

```
return (IList)this.mydata;
```

**Update**

Based on your update, you will have to update `MyData` to implement `IList` otherwise you have no choice but to return a new collection which *does* implement it.

Alternatively, if `MyData` is indeed a generic list then I would suggest you have it inherit from `List<T>`, that way you get a lot more flexibility & compatibility out of the box e.g.

```
class MyData : List<MyDataRow>
{
}
```

Comment: That does explain the problem, but doesn't provide a solution: myData is of type IList<MyDataRow>, he would still need to call .ToList() and he wants to avoid that.

Comment: @Baboon if `myData` is of type `IList<MyDataRow>`, but the concrete type is `List<T>` then an explicit cast is all that is needed.

Comment: Thanks, James, for your detailed answer. I am going to give you the credit because the suggestion to inherit from List<T>, rather than encapsulating a List<T> member in my class as I was doing, was indeed the simplest solution to my problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

The `MyData` class need to implement the `IList` along with the generic version `IList<T>`.

```
class MyData : IList<MyDataRow>, IList
{
}
```

Comment: +1. I took the liberty of fixing the class name. (According to the OP's error message, the class itself is MyData, not MyDataRow).

Answer (score 4):

`IList<T>` does not extend `IList`, because it's not reasonable to expect every implementation of the generic version to offer the same contract as the non-generic one. If it did extend `IList`, someone could take the value returned from `GetList` and reasonably expect to call, e.g. `Add(DateTime.Now)`, or `Add(Thread.CurrentThread)`. That's what `IList` promises.

That's the reason copying your list to a `List<T>` works - `List<T>` implements *both* interfaces, and throws when its (explicitly implemented) `IList` methods are called with inappropriate parameter types.

If you can get away with returning `IEnumerable`, do that instead. If you can return `IList<MyDataRow>` instead, then do that. If you really need a non-generic `IList` return, then implement the interface and handle non-`MyDataRow` values appropriately.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the dangers of implementing `IList` along with `IList<T>`

Answer (score 4):

Either implement `IList` on your data collection class or create an adapter, which wraps `IList<T>` and implements `IList`:

```
public sealed class NonGenericList<T> : IList
{
    private readonly IList<T> _wrappedList;

    public NonGenericList(IList<T> wrappedList)
    {
        if(wrappedList == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("wrappedList");

        _wrappedList = wrappedList;
    }

    public int Add(object value)
    {
        _wrappedList.Add((T)value);
        return _wrappedList.Count - 1;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _wrappedList.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(object value)
    {
        return _wrappedList.Contains((T)value);
    }

    public int IndexOf(object value)
    {
        return _wrappedList.IndexOf((T)value);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        _wrappedList.Insert(index, (T)value);
    }

    public bool IsFixedSize
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return _wrappedList.IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public void Remove(object value)
    {
        _wrappedList.Remove((T)value);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _wrappedList.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public object this[int index]
    {
        get { return _wrappedList[index]; }
        set { _wrappedList[index] = (T)value; }
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        _wrappedList.CopyTo((T[])array, index);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _wrappedList.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get { return this; }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _wrappedList.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public System.Collections.IList GetList()
{
    return new NonGenericList<MyDataRow>(this._mydata);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it were possible to convert an `IList<T>` into an `IList` directly, you could return a list that could (for example) be "contaminated" with non `T` objects via its `Add(object)` method.

Comment: Your second paragraph gets to the crux of it, but the first one seems a little off - the compile error happens precisely because `IList<T>` is *not* derived from `IList`.

Comment: Excellent point. Amended accordingly, and thanks for the correction. You're absolutely right.